# Unterminated character class using square brackets

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I'm pulling in a web data source and need to clean it up. In Pebble JS I've used the following which works on a standard web page:

```
    var arr = JSON.parse('[' + str.replace(/\]\[/gi, '],[') + ']');
    console.log(arr);
```

This returns the error 'Unterminated character class'. I've tried various methods of escaping the characters but no success.

Comment: Are you using pebble.js or PebbleKit JavaScript with a C app? And are you testing in the simulator? Android phone? iOS Phone?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info : pebble.js testing in the simulator.

Comment: Probably a bug on our end. Looking into it...

Comment: we could never reproduce the problem. Please contact devsupport@getpebble.com with a zip of your project or the URL of the project in CloudPebble. Thanks a lot!